# Bootstrap 4 .modal('hide') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a really simple, but a bit tweaked, modal for showing an iFrame. I open the model by a javascript function and the modal call function provided by bootstrap. In my modal I've placed an icon for closing the modal. If I click on this close icon the modal won't hide. I use a javascript onclick with the `.modal('show')` and `.modal('hide')` functions provided by bootstrap. The modal doesn't hide, but my console log is fired.

I know there are many questions out there with a similiar problem but these questions did not contain the answer I was looking for. I know that css in html is just not right, but I was doing some fast prototyping so please forgive me for that.

Code

Open link for modal

```
<a href="#" onClick="openFeedback('getBootstrap')">Klik hier om de website te bekijken</a>
```

The modal html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="iframe_feedback" style="padding-top: 20px;">

  <i class="ion-close-round close-modal" style="position: fixed; right: 40px; font-size: 32px; color: white; top: 40px; cursor: pointer;" onClick="closeModal()"></i>

  <div class="body-modal" style="max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: scroll;">

    <div id="clip" style="overflow:scroll;">
        <iframe src="/dashboard" style=" width:2600px; height: 1600px;"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>  

</div>
```

The JS

```
function openFeedback(link) {
    $('#iframe_feedback').modal('show');
    console.log(link);
};

function closeModal() {

    $("#iframe_feedback").modal('hide');
    console.log('Close fired');

};
```

My main problem is that my modal is showing up, also fires the `console.log` for both show and hide but after clicking on the close button the modal doesn't hide.

Comment: Do you see something in the console? Maybe you're getting an error.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete Like I said, my console.log both times fired so I would notice if there was an error. Don't see any problems or errors.

Comment: Have you tried using an anonymous function in your jquery rather than using click events? So do `$('.close-modal').on('click'`....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TLDR;

It seems like you **need the `modal-dialog`** div inside your modal for `.modal('hide')` or `data-dismiss="modal"` to work.

### --

I got your problem fixed by changing the `body-modal` class to **`modal-dialog`**. (*and changed your close icon to red so that it can be seen easier in the snippet*)

```js
function openFeedback(link) {
    $('#iframe_feedback').modal('show');
    console.log(link);
};

function closeModal() {

    $("#iframe_feedback").modal('hide');
    console.log('Close fired');

};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" onClick="openFeedback('getBootstrap')">Klik hier om de website te bekijken</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="iframe_feedback" style="padding-top: 20px;">
  <i class="ion-close-round close-modal" style="position: fixed; right: 40px; font-size: 32px; color: red; top: 40px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1700;" onClick="closeModal()">close</i>
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: scroll;">
    <div id="clip" style="overflow:scroll;">
      <iframe src="/dashboard" style=" width:2600px; height: 1600px;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But now the modal is bit messy (visually).

I'd recommend that you check the [modal docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/). With the included features in Bootstrap 4 you would probably strip off most of your extra (inline) CSS and JS, and in this way ensure that your everything works well in the most of browsers.

Comment: Well yeah, I figured out. I knew about that `modal-dialog` class but I did remove that class on purepose for my initial goal. That's why my question was why this wasn't working, acutally without the `modal-dialog` class. I've tweaked the modal for some reasons, also because the docs were not clear enough about my goal (scrolling in the modal). Yet I think that your answer is as close it can get to answer the question so thanks! I've made some edits to help users a good answer.

Comment: @Gijsberts Have you seen [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content) about scrolling in the modal?

Answer (score 17):

If you remove the `fade` class it works fine.

I think that you need a `modal-dialog` div if you intent to use the `fade` class. Also, use just one type of closing/opening modals, either the js way or the `data-toggle/data-dismiss`.

Comment: Well actually I like that `fade` class and also figured out that it will only work with the `modal-dialog` class. But the problem was I actually removed that `modal-dialog` class on purpose. That's why I am asking why this isn't working aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-dismiss="modal" for close the modal

`<i class="ion-close-round close-modal" style="position: fixed; right: 40px; font-size: 32px; color: white; top: 40px; cursor: pointer;" data-dismiss="modal" ></i>`